# How to call a java webservice using python

Tags: java, python, sql, web-services

I want to access the SQL database from ubuntu 11.10. It's not possible to install SQL software in my ubuntu. Some suggested that to use webservice to access database from other sytem which has the database. Can anyone tell me the procedure to call a webservice which is written in java by some one else. I need to call the Web service in my python & plone project. But I'm not using any IDE for developing code.  I don't have any experience in Web services. SO Please explain me the clear steps to hit the database.

Comment: Hope for the best! "But i m not using any IDE for developing code."

Comment: Surely, you need to provide more details on what you're exactly trying to achieve and where you are facing problems. Why is it not possible to install SQL software (like MySQL) on your ubuntu? What database do you want to access? Do you currently have it hosted somewhere or you want to create one? Without knowing any details, I'm afraid nobody can answer this question.

Comment: @Swapnil: Hi,I tried to install SQL on my ubuntu but it does not help me. I want to access MS SQL only not MySQL. SQL Server is hosted in other sytem which has the complete database for the project which i m currently working. So only i asking help to start with the webservice

Comment: @Srinivas: Hi, I never used any IDE for Developing a Project. I usually work with file system. Is it possible to do webservice without IDE

Comment: A webservice call is code. What does use of IDE have with ability to write code?